# Why doesn't this object reference work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to populate this list with strings from the object data. It comes out as 'undefined'. It's the reference to the data object that doesn't work. Why?

**JS**

```
data = [
        {"q":"How much?", "ac":"20%", "a1": "1%", "a2": "10%", "a3": "5%"},
        {"q":"What", "ac":"Ball", "a1": "Stone", "a2": "Bierd", "a3": "Carl"},
        {"q":"When?", "ac":"1999", "a1": "2000", "a2": "2001", "a3": "2002"}
        ];      

var q=0

window.onload = function() {
    var ids =['a','b','c','d'];
    var ans =['a1','a2','a3','ac'];
    for (var j=0; j < ids.length; j++) {
    var a = ans[j];
    document.getElementsByClassName(ids[j])[0].innerHTML = data[q].a; //[<-- PROBLEM HERE]

};
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="answers_quiz">
<li class="a"></li>
<li class="b"></li>
<li class="c"></li>
<li class="d"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the square bracket syntax rather than the dot syntax to use a variable as a property accessor:

```
element.innerHTML = data[q][a];
```

The dot syntax looks for a property named "a" in `data[q]`. Since there is no such thing, it returns `undefined`. When you use the array notation, it looks for a property named whatever `a` contains.

For example, on the first iteration, when `a === "a1"`, `data[q].a1` is equivalent to `data[q][a]`.